# Native vs. Protothreads, what is easier?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I just stumbled on Protothreads. They seems superior to native threads since context switch are explicit.

My question is. Makes this multi-threaded programming an easy task again?

(I think so. But have I missed something?)

Comment: "context switch are explicit". And so we come full circle back to Windows 3 and co-operative multi-tasking. I wouldn't say that multi-threaded programming without pre-emption is "easy" - it's easier to avoid races and deadlocks, but harder to avoid one runaway task making the system unresponsive.

Comment: ... embedded programmers aren't so concerned by the latter. They're used to having to make real-time guarantees, so they know lots of ways to avoid slow non-interruptible operations. If the same techniques work for your app, then threads may be an unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Thanks. I learned a lot. I did not have the mental picture of security of untrusted software. It's clear this is two different kind of problems I compare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're not "superior" - they're just different and fit another purpose. Protothreads are simulated, and hence aren't real threads. They won't run on multiple cores, and they will all block on a single system call (socket recv() and such). Hence you shouldn't see it as a "silver bullet" that solves all multithreading problems. Such threads have existed for Java, Ruby and Python for quite some time now.

On the other hand, they're very lightweight so they do make some tasks quicker and simpler. They're suitable for small embedded systems because of low code and memory footprint. If you design your whole system (including an "OS", as is customary on small embedded devices) from the ground up, protothreads can provide a simple way to achieve concurrency.

Also read on [green threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads).

Comment: I doubt that any serious servers use green threads, because they need blocking IO (socket) calls to operate

Comment: Web servers don't HAVE to use blocking calls, do they? I thought non-blocking would be better.